# Angular ng-style does not automatically apply changes when I change it from controller

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I have some content where I use ng-style, here is part of the template html:

```
<div ui-tree-handle data-nodrag 
     class="tree-node tree-node-content" 
     ng-click="toggle(this)" 
     ng-style={{breddeCSS}}>
```

the breddeCSS is defined in the controller here:

```
      function setBreddeCSS(b) {

          switch (b) {

              case 0:
                  $scope.breddeCSS = {
                      "margin": "-1px",
                  };
                  break;

              case 1:
                  $scope.breddeCSS = {
                      "margin": "5px",
                  };
                  break;

              default:
                  $scope.breddeCSS = {
                      "margin": "10px",
                  };
          }

      }
```

The template gets the margin style, but only when the site is first loaded. If I change the $scope.bredde, it is only when the page is refreshed that I see the change!

I would like the page to change dynamically everytime $scope.bredde is updated. How can I do this?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava `breddeCSS` is an object, not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngStyle` requires an expression itself not the resulf of its evaluation. [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

```
<div ui-tree-handle data-nodrag 
     class="tree-node tree-node-content" 
     ng-click="toggle(this)" 
     ng-style="breddeCSS">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RxTte5njdS8GfTiD73LA?p=preview